# Always Encrypted : Certificate with thumbprint not found in certificate store

Tags: sql-server, always-encrypted

I have a mvc application that uses sql express 2016.

I have follow all the necessary steps to configure **always encrypted** to one of my columns in the table. And install Certificate to my machine for testing purpose. All Works Fine in my local environment.

Now my concern is that, After hosting my Application on web server. While Accessing column through Appilcation i got error,

> Certificate with thumbprint 'XXXXXXXXXXX' not found in certificate store 'My' in certificate location 'CurrentUser'. Verify the certificate path in the column master key definition in the database is correct, and the certificate has been imported correctly into the certificate location/store.Parameter name: masterKeyPath

And what if i only want a particular user can access that decrypted column through application, is it possible by installing certificate on that single user's machine instead of hosting server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you can export the **Always Encrypted Certificate** in ***'.pfx'*** format.

The user can then **import(/install)** the .pfx certificate in their local user account, and will be able to access the **data in encrypted columns**.